# ¿Cuáles son las palabras de origen africano con mayor antigüedad en español?

Tags: etimología, historia, préstamo-lingüístico

El vocabulario del español suelen tener un origen mayoritariamente 'europeo' (latín, griego, lenguas celtas, germanas...), con un aporte significativo del árabe, de las lenguas americanas y un menor aporte del resto del mundo... pero esta pregunta va enfocada a las palabras de un origen africano, y no precisamente de dialectos del árabe. ¿Existen palabras cuya etimología se describa como africana antes del siglo XX? ¿Cuáles son esas palabras?

Comment: El  mambo es de origen africano, pero no sé si es antiguo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

| Word | First appearance | Etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***Gato*** | 1495, Nebrija | via Late Latin *cattus*, ultimately of African origin (possibly Berber). |
| ***Girafa*** | 1516, Nebrija | from Italian *giraffa*, from Arabic زَرَافَة‎ (*zarāfa*), probably of African origin; of the same family as Egyptian *sr* "giraffe". |
| ***Mondongo*** | 1604, Palet |  |
| ***Banana*** | 1706, Stevens | of Wolof origin. |
| ***Marimba*** | 1721, Bluteau | of Bantu origin. |
| ***Ñame*** | 1817, RAE | of West African (possibly Kongo) origin. Possibly related to Fulani *nyame*. |
| ***Cachimba*** | 1846, Salvá | via Portuguese *cacimba*, from Bantu *cazimba*. |
| ***Chimpanzé*** | 1853, Gaspar y Roig | derived from an unspecified Bantu language of Angola, comparable to Vili *ci-mpenzi*. |

---

<sup>https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Spanish_words_of_African_origin</sup>

Answer (score 9):

La palabra más antigua de origen africano que ha llegado directamente al español (sin pasar a través de otros idiomas, como el árabe, francés, etc.) que he encontrado es

> [**marimba**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OQ0djjf)
>   De or. africano.
>   1. f. Especie de tambor que se usa en algunas partes de África.
>   2. f. Instrumento musical en que se percuten listones de madera, como en el xilófono.
>   3. f. *Am*. Instrumento musical en que se percuten con un macillo blando tiras de vidrio, como en el tímpano.

en el diccionario de **Salvá (1846)** y en el DRAE (1869).